# how to set adapter leftcall image and text and right call only text in android

Tags: android

This is my code for adapter class:

```
 public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chat> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<Chat> values;
        ImageLoader imageloader;
        Datamodel dm;

        public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Chat> values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_row_layout_odd, values);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
            imageloader = new ImageLoader(context);
        }

        public void addMessage(Chat chat) {
            values.add(chat);
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_odd,
                        parent, false);

            RoundedImageView userImg = (RoundedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_img);

            RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.even_container);
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            RoundedImageView oddImg = (RoundedImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.odd_bubble);


            ImageView leftimageicon=(ImageView)root.findViewById(R.id.left);
            ImageView rightimageicon=(ImageView)root.findViewById(R.id.right);

            Typeface fontArial = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/ARIAL.TTF");

            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                    AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String K = prefs.getString("Member_id", "");
            Chat chat = values.get(position);

            String t = chat.getRecieverID();

            tv.setText(chat.getMessage());

            tv.setTypeface(fontArial);

            AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);

            if (chat.getSenderID().equals(prefs.getString("Member_id", ""))) {
                root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#636363"));
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ad9a"));
                leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rightimageicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                oddImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                oddImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                aq.id(oddImg).image(
                        "http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/" + K + ".jpg");
                leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rightimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                oddImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

list_row_layout_odd.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/even_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/odd_bubble"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/shareRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/odd_bubble"
            android:background="#07000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:layout_weight=".10"
                android:src="@drawable/callout_left" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="155dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/left"
                android:textColor="#636363"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"![enter image description here][1]
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text"
                android:layout_weight=".10"
                android:src="@drawable/callout_right" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

i am able to display chatlistview But there is problem i am unable to set item according to screen i am trying to set left and right textview but right textview not going to design . i have to make adapter so that i can sperate send and receiver textview and image view according to given screen .and below is desire screen :
below is my current screen : respectively

[image]
[image]
i dont know  where am doing mistake please tell me and suggest me .

Comment: add some weight to android:id="@+id/text" this text view and check in list_row_layout_odd.xml

Comment: yes its working fine But i want to set right textview which i colored full text without image  u can see in gdesire screen

Comment: May be its in list_row_layout_even then use Linear layout and add two textview and set weightsome for that. I know its not good but just chesc is that working for you. So you will get idea how to to implement in other way. Best luck

Comment: i tried this but still its not working its givng Exception null PointerException  rightimageicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   oddImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);  here please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/even_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10" >

        <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/odd_bubble"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.90" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/shareRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:background="#07000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/left"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".10"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:textColor="#636363"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please check this xml and change according to your requirement

Comment: and com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView change its width wrap_content

Comment: good now its coming like this but still we have to set margin from both side u can see in desire screen how  i will set that programmatically  http://snag.gy/sUNNx.jpg